What is 得な性格? How is it used in this sentence?

Context: The character's brother asked him to meet a person for him. The character is reluctant but in the end he comments  his brother's 強引さ always makes him do stuff etc.
I can gather he's complaining about his brother's 得な性格 personality given the やがる however after some googling I get mixed results regarding the nature of the word. One of the meaning I can find is akin to "Lovable" but I'm not quite sure it fits?

The brother has an “advantageous” or persuasive personality that allows him to have his way over others. The やがって indicates that the character is envious or disdainful of it.
The opposite is 損な性格
